# Traceflowsolver

Tags: arcobjects, vba

I am working with VBA in ArcGIS.I want to use "Traceflowsolver.findpath" but I recieved an error on "SegmentCost".I need to see an example about this subject .anyone can help me?
Also my code is:
" traceFlowSolver.FindPath esriFMDownstream, esriSPObjFnMinSum, junctionEIDs, edjeEIDs, count, Segment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning weights first using INetSolverWeights.

**Update:**  See [this sample](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/CPP_VB6_VBA_VCPP_Doc/COM_Samples_Docs/Network/Path_Finder/Visual_Basic/cPathFinder.cls.htm):

```
' get the INetSchema interface
  Set ipNetSchema = ipNetwork
  Set ipNetWeight = ipNetSchema.WeightByName(WeightName)
  Debug.Assert Not ipNetWeight Is Nothing

  ' set the weight (use the same for both directions)
  Set ipNetSolverWeights = ipTraceFlowSolver
  Set ipNetSolverWeights.FromToEdgeWeight = ipNetWeight
  Set ipNetSolverWeights.ToFromEdgeWeight = ipNetWeight
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! 
But I couldn't solve the problem with your advice yet.

Comment: see my update above.

Comment: tnx alot.My problem is solved and I can do my thesis.